# Conditional Fields Module works for 1 day then errors out

Tags: 7, entities

I installed [Conditional Fields](https://www.drupal.org/project/conditional_fields) - version 7.x-3.0-alpha1 and everything was working fine. I left for the day and came back the next day to these errors showing on any of the conditional fields pages:

```
Notice: Undefined index: conditional_fields_dependency_add_form_comment_comment_node_page in drupal_retrieve_form() (line 765 of /var/www/vhosts/drupaldev/httpdocs/includes/form.inc).
Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'conditional_fields_dependency_add_form_comment_comment_node_page' not found or invalid function name in drupal_retrieve_form() (line 800 of /var/www/vhosts/drupaldev/httpdocs/includes/form.inc).
(The error log was too long to paste, see the full thing here: http://pastebin.com/ufY8U5by )
```

Now, the odd part is if I just disable and re-enable the module, the errors go away and I am able to edit the settings fine for about 1 day. Every time I leave work and come back, the errors have returned the next day.

I have also deleted the mod and re-installed which had the same temporary effect of working for 1 day. I also re-applied the permissions to the module folder which also made it work for 1 day.

Now, this site I have recently taken over and it has a lot of custom code spread all over the place already so I am not even sure where to begin to look. Something each night (I am guessing) is running on the site and causing this module to break. Some kind of nightly maintenance thing or such? Does anyone have any clue where I should be looking first to try and get this fixed?

Thanks!

Comment: You can check for cron runs? It is common that cron runs every night (not Drupal cron).

Comment: this should be made as a bug report on the module page itself... especially since it's alpha1 - you may find you get more direct help there